# Triangle lower bound of a convex function

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, derivatives, convex-geometry

Suppose the function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is convex on $[T,\infty)$.

Let $\delta=f(t)/|f'(t)|$ then the triangle $T$ determined by the points $(t,f(t)), (t,0)$ and $(t,t+\delta)$ lies below the graph of $f$ for all $t\geq T$.

---

I cannot confirm that the point $(t,t+\delta)$ does lie below the graph of $f$. I tried to play around the tangent definition of convex function:
$$
f(x)\geq f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)
$$
but unable to get anywhere.

---

(Edit: I have attached a picture of the source material 06-01-2021)

[image]

Comment: The three vertices of your triangle $T$ have the same $x$-coordinates?

Comment: I think there is a typo from the source material. This is from "The Cauchy-Schwarz Masterclass" Ex 7.7. I would guess $(t,0)$ is supposed to be $(0,t)$. I don't believe it is important to the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In case $f'(t)=0$, one can check either the integral is infinity, or the integral is $0$, meaning $f=0$ on $[t, \infty)$ and $f(t)=0$, you can interpret $f(t)^2/|f'(t)|=0$.